# what actually param(this.otherParam) means in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am using Kotlin since few time and I found some code that I really dont understand why is for. Testing it seems like the return is `Unit`

basically I did this:

```
sealed class User {

}

data class ActiveUser(val name: String, val lastName: String, val email: String) : User () {

fun <T> doSomething(name: String.() -> T?) =
        name(this.email) ?:  throw RuntimeException("Error")

}
```

Create a class from where I inherit ActiveUser and receive some parameters.

I dont understand why is like this

```
String.() -> T?
```

I found the info for that https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver

But still I dont understand…

and the most shocking for me… how is possible that the parameter name can be used a method?

**name(this.email)**

what does it do? what does it actually mean?

Debugging it seems like do nothing... how is this possible?

I test it this way, maybe Im missing something

```
fun main() {
    val activeUser: ActiveUser
    activeUser= ActiveUser("John", "Doe", "john@doe.com")
    activeUser.doSomething {"some name" }
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329716/what-is-a-purpose-of-lambdas-with-receiver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875491/what-is-a-receiver-in-kotlin