# Understanding a parameter that is initialized as an extension function

Tags: kotlin

In the following code the parameter type for modelInitializer is
`CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder.()`

What does the `.()` mean?. I believe the dot refers to an extension. And when you `add ()` after it, I think it means to create an instance of this type. Does this mean some anonymous extension is being created here and initialized?

```
inline fun EpoxyController.calendarMonthTitle(modelInitializer: CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder.() ->
        Unit) {
    CalendarMonthTitleModel_().apply  {
        modelInitializer()
    }
    .addTo(this)
}
```

What happens if you leave out the dot before `()`?

Comment: 1. the answer is in the title of your question: it's an extension function. 2. Try, and you'll see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a purpose of Lambda's with Receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329716/what-is-a-purpose-of-lambdas-with-receiver)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct name for this is called [lambda with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

You've started in the right direction. So an easy way to think of this is by starting in extension functions:

```
fun CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder.foo() = //...
```

The function `foo` is an extension function on the type `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder`.

Let's approach it from another angle. Let's talk about higher-order functions, a.k.a. functions that take other functions as parameters:

```
fun higherOrder(func: () -> Unit) = //...
```

This function receives a `lambda` that receives no parameters and returns `Unit`. What could one do if we wanted to use a `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder` inside the lambda? An easy way is to pass it in:

```
fun higherOrder(func: (CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder) -> Unit) = //...
```

Calling this function, would be something like this:

```
higherOrder {
   it.someMethod()
}
```

*(here someMethod is part of CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder)*

However, we can somehow make this lambda an extension to `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder` by using a similar sytax to the extension functions:

```
fun higherOrder(func: CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder.() -> Unit) = //...
```

The difference now, is that we've created a lambda with receiver, meaning instead of using the implicit parameter `it`, we can use `this`, or better yet, omit it:

```
higherOrder {
   someMethod()
}
```

inside the lambda, `this` is an instance of `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder`, so you can simply call `someMethod`.

These constructs are often used in DSL's and you see them a lot in examples like yours - with the builder pattern.

---

Here's a very simple example. Let's assume you have `UserBuilder` class that builds users and you want to create a small DSL for this (this is an exaggeration of the pattern, but suits to help out I think):

```
data class User(
    val email: String,
    val password: String)

class UserBuilder {
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""

    fun build() = User(email, password)
}
```

One can begin by writing a higher-order function like so:

```
fun user(func: UserBuilder.() -> Unit) =
    UserBuilder().apply(func)
```

Inside the method, we create an instance of the builder and apply to it the lambda. This is a simple trick so we can keep on chaining the methods and at the end call `build`. For example:

```
user {
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    password = "123456"
}.build()
```

It's possible to go even further using extension functions:

```
fun UserBuilder.withEmail(emailBuilder: () -> String) {
  email = emailBuilder()
}
```

Which let's you do:

```
user {
    withEmail {
        "foo@bar.com"
    }
}.build()
```

we can call `withEmail` inside `user` because `withEmail` is an extension function on `UserBuilder` and inside `user` `this` is of type `UserBuilder` due to the lambda with receiver.

You can do something similar to the password.

Comment: What does DSL stand for?

Comment: `domain specific language`, basically you create a specific language to your use case. This is usually manifested in the form of several methods. I've added an example, which hopefully explains it better.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. But it really didn't help. I had to take your code samples and actually run them to really understand what was going on and that took me around an hour. Take the case where I remove the dot in user(func: UserBuilder.() -> Unit). It generates an error message of "Top level declaration expected" - That's a totally useless error message.

Comment: One final note. Personally I find the word "extension" for ```fun user(func: UserBuilder.() -> Unit)``` very misleading as I don't see anything in this that actually extends some existing functionality, whereas ```fun UserBuilder.withEmail``` is clearly extending an existing object. But hey, that's just my opinion.

Comment: I understand. By extending I meant that inside the scope of the function, `UserBuilder` has a new anonymous method, meaning the lambda you call is actually on the `UserBuilder` object you've created. Also, since the dot syntax is pretty close to extension functions, I thought it would help. Sorry for the misleading information.

Comment: is there a equivalent  feature for this on java  or can someone point me to a reference  ? {i am using kotlin based extensions in a java project..}

Answer (score 1):

First of all `()->Unit` is a lambda. And this lambda has a `this`, and it's type is the `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder`. It's called lambda with a receiver.

So inside `modelInitializer` you can access to `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder` as you are inside this class: using `this`.

For example, I assume that `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder` has a `someMethod`:

```
val epoxyController: EpoxyController = EpoxyController()

epoxyController.calendarMonthTitle {
    // inside these curlies `this: CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder = CalendarMonthTitleModel_()`
    this.someMethod() //you can use 'this' inside this lambda
    someMethod() // or as usual just skip writing 'this', just access `CalendarMonthTitleModelBuilder` methods as you inside it's class

}
```

This feature is essential in building DSLs.

Here is  a link to [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types).