# Explanation needed for Kotlin receiver function use for DSL

Tags: kotlin, dsl

I'm trying to understand the following code ([source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)).

```
class HTML {
    fun body() { ... }
}

fun html(init: HTML.() -> Unit): HTML {
    val html = HTML()  // create the receiver object
    html.init()        // pass the receiver object to the lambda
    return html
}

html {       // lambda with receiver begins here
    body()   // calling a method on the receiver object
}
```

What I really cannot grasp is the line

```
html.init() // pass the receiver object to the lambda
```

What is happening here?

Can somebody please explain in simple words what is going on here?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329866/4465208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's make this example a little easier and see what the problem is then.

We could build the `html` function like this:

```
fun html(init: (HTML) -> Unit): HTML {
    val html = HTML()
    init(html)
    return html
}
```

This would be easier to grasp (at first), because we are just passing a usual one-parameter lambda to the `html` function.

But now the call-site is not builder like:

```
html { it: HTML -> // just for clarity     
    it.body() // not very nice
}
```

Wouldn't it be nice if we could invoke `body()` inside `html` without `it`? That's possible! All we need is a lambda with receiver.

```
fun html(init: HTML.() -> Unit): HTML { // <-- only this changed
    val html = HTML()
    init(html)
    return html
}
```

See how `html` is passed as an argument to `init` like before? 
Of course, we can invoke it like this too: `html.init()` as shown in the example. The instance of `HTML` becomes `this` inside the block of the lambda.

Now, we can do this:

```
html {      
   this.body()
}
```

Since `this` can be omitted, we arrive here:

```
html {      
   body()
}
```

So, in the end lambdas with receivers make the code more concise and allow us to use a nice builder syntax.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is step by step explaination:**

*1. Creation of function, receiver type lambda.*

```kotlin
fun html(init: HTML.() -> Unit): HTML {
```

here function html accept a parameter `init` of type `HTML.() -> Unit` i.e. it indicated that it is a receiver of HTML and can only be called with help of a real HTML object. And `: HTML` indicates that the function obviously returns HTML object.

*2. call of init at html*

```kotlin
html.init()
```

Here init() function is called as a receiver of HTML by a real HTML object.

---

**Alright enough of formal talking, Here is what a receiver is:**

So if you remember extension function defined as `fun A.myFun(...): ReturnType {}`, in that case you get a variable `this` which act as an instance of type A it was called on.

Similarly receiver lambda gives you a `this` variable inside that,

In a particular example:

```kotlin
class A {
    fun thisCanBeCalledByAInstance() {
        println("I've got called")
    }

}

fun main() {
    val receiver: A.() -> Unit = { // this: A
        thisCanBeCalledByAInstance() // prints: I've got called
        // or traditional way this.thisCanBeCalledByAInstance()
    }

    val a: A = A()
    a.receiver()
}
```

Here you were able to call the method(function) from the instance of `A` even if it was lambda because it was a receiver.

**PS: For simple langauge you can think html.init() as init(html) but html is not a parameter but instead works as `this` vaiable inside the lambda**

This is why you were able to call `body()` on that lambda, because implicitly you were calling `this.body()` and `this` has came from `html.init()`'s html object.